# Laravel 5 on shared hosting getting internal server error

Tags: deployment, ftp, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I am trying to get my Laravel 5 project running on my shared hosting through FTP.

I have uploaded all my project files from my local XAMP-folder to the server root directory and put the files in the 'public' folder in the public_html folder.

When I go to mydomain.com I get redirected to mydomain.com/auth/login as I set in my routes.php so that seem to be working although I'm getting 500 internal server error on all paths.

Comment: do you have .htaccess file in your root folder ?

Comment: Only in public_html, but I tried with a .htaccess like this in the root folder with no success:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: have you followed a tutorial for hosting your laravel on shared host ? if yeas please link it

Comment: Something like method #1 here: https://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host but I placed all core app files in the root because that way I didn't have to change the paths in my index.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes this is because the storage folder is not writeable by the server. One possible way is go via ssh into the app (i.e. /path/to/mywebsite) and then do

```
chmod -R 777 storage/
```

Because logs, caches, need to be written there. Or you can also do that with the FTP app (just make everything executable, readable, writeable).

**UPDATE:**

Another solution (that I use every now and then - and apparently also worked here :-) ) is to add

```
RewriteBase /
```

as a line right after

```
RewriteEngine On
```

in the .htaccess file.

Comment: 777 on storage does not seem to resolve it... however I don't see any error logs written either

Comment: How about adding "RewriteBase /" as a line right after "RewriteEngine On" in the .htaccess?

Comment: That worked, many thanks! Add it as an answer and I will upvote it

Answer (score 1):

Laravel requires storage to be readable, writable, and executable by all, so you need to run

```
chmod -R 777 storage/
```

That usually solves the problem, but if Internal Server 500 still persists, run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

then

```
php artisan optimize
```